# Callback после FB-connect

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-api

Всем добрый день!
Делаю комментарии на сайте с возможностью залогиниться через соц-сети и столкнулся с кажется мелкой, но досадной проблемой: не могу "словить" момент, когда юзер успешно залогинивается в Facebook. Для залогинивания использую fb:login-button.
Гуглил нещадно, но толку нет. Сразу оговорюсь, что мне не нужно вручную вызывать FB.login() - это не подходит, нужно перехватить стандартный клик по иконке. Может кто-то сталкивался с подобным? Буду рад конструктивной помощи :)
Подменить клик по кнопке и заменить своим не предлагать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Точно не проверял но в офф. документации написано что нужно просто поставить обработчик для события когда пользователь авторизуется при помощи вот этого [метода](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/).

Вот на эти события можно подписаться:

- auth.statusChange
- authResponseChange (replaces auth.sessionChange)
- auth.login
- auth.logout

Т.е. в вашей ситуации код будет каким то таким:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login',
  function(response) {
    // Что то делаем с response, например выводим в консоль
    console.log(response);
  }
);
```

Comment: Большущее спасибо! Очень помогли :) Сколько я не курил их маны, так и не въехал во все хитрости... Еще раз спасибо :)

Comment: Рад, что помог, удачи с проектом! ;)